# Trouble Opening Chrome Browser with Selenium and User Data Directory; Conflicts with Existing Chrome Instances

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to launch the Chrome browser using Selenium with the user-data-dir option to load a specific profile. However, if another instance of Chrome is already open, it crashes and fails to function. I've tried various approaches but haven't found a solution yet.

```
 public Object initializationWebDriver(String url, Class classToProxy) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/chromedriver121.exe");
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/downloadFiles");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
        prefs.put("download.default_directory", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\downloadFiles");
        prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false); // Optional: Disable download prompt

        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/ydmor/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
        options.addArguments("profile-directory=Profile 5");
        options.addArguments("remote-debugging-port=9292")  ;

...
```

and this is the error

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-PSMOVHL', ip: '192.168.1.159'
Build info: version: '4.5.0', revision: 'fe167b119a'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.6'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```